# Is this theoretically valid method to protect against SQL injections?

Tags: sql, code-injection

I know there are methods (escaping/ prepared statements) to protect against injections. However, for "fun", do you think the following method works?

Assume you are given a string. You get the string and add "space" between every character.

This way, even if there is a security breach somehow, commands will not make sense because adding the "space" invalidates them.

I understand there are performance issues and stuff... But in theory, will it work?

Comment: You're planning on implementing this, aren't you?

Comment: Thinking about doing it for a table to see what happens.

Comment: If your intended defence against SQL injection is to 'encode' the data in some way then this will probably work, but, for example, base64 encoding would probably be faster and less wasteful. But why bother? You've already alluded to the proper way to do things. Do it properly.

Comment: Escaping isn't viable either.  Just use parameter queries and be done with it.

Comment: What's the point? Adding a space between all characters will almost certainly negate the point of running the query in the first place. E.g you will search for "b o b" instead of "Bob".

Comment: The point was to have a "second" layer of defense in case breach is found, due to some bug or other reason.

Comment: I remember some SQL RDBMS only parsing the first 4096 characters of a query.  This class of attack would still work.  If the client is not using the correct charset when inserting the spaces, you may also be able to work out two-byte UTF8 sequences which end in 0x20 that could be attacked.

Answer (score 2):

No.

[SQL injection is defined as the modification of the intended SQL command.](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/89.html) If even a single character is able to modify it (e. g., a single quote prematurely ends the string literal, resulting in a syntax error), it is considered an SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is sort of an "opinion" based question I'm still going to answer. "No." :)  This will not safeguard against all possible cases.  Most likely it will simply make some forms of injection more difficult, but certainly not all.  Here's why.

Introducing spaces will not properly solve the problem, in addition to rendering the data into a format that is unlikely to reflect what you really want to store.  For example, some applications will introduce user input as integer values in database lookups.

Given:

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=$user_input_value
```

User input:
     1OR1=1

Rendered statement:

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE id= 1 OR 1 = 1
```

This remains completely valid SQL and will return all rows in the table.  Whitespace around the equals sign will be discarded.

Comment: The OR would be broken up, too. The problem is that you can work with only single character syntax elements.

Comment: I see. So I guess if I try to use other char, there may be another corner case which I haven't thought about. I will put this as the correct answer for countering the "space". EDIT: True, the OR will be broken up too :D

Comment: I'd recommend that you simply use the parameterized queries provided via the driver that guarantee proper handling. :)

Answer (score 1):

This will break up any operator or keywords of more than one character. An attacker would need to cause damage using single characters separated by spaces. Let's see what we can do with that.

Assume a one-character column named `c`:

```
SELECT 1
FROM (VALUES (1234)) x(c)
WHERE c = '" + injectedSql + "'
```

Inject

```
' + c + '
```

which gives:

```
SELECT 1
FROM (VALUES (1234)) x(c)
WHERE c = '' + c + ''
```

Pwned.